# C*-algebra inequality closed under pertubation?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Let $a \in A_+$, the positive cone of $A$. Let $f,g \geq 0$ be real functions with compact supports contained in $(0,\infty)$. Further, assume that $g(x) = f(x) + 1$ for all $x$ in the support of $f$. So, we have something like this:

[image]

Now, from functional calculus, $f(a) \leq g(a)$ and in fact any positive $b$ in the C*-algebra generated by $a$ that is close to $g(a)$ will be greater than $f(a)$. What I'm unable to figure out is whether this holds, more generally, in all of $A$.

> **Question**: Is there an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $b \in A_+$, and $\|b-g(a)\| < \epsilon$ implies $f(a) \leq b$?
>
> *Added: note the crucial assumption that $b \geq 0$*

Roughly does the controlled gap between $f$ and $g$ imply that $g(a)$ is "substantially" bigger than $f(a)$ in the above precise sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take $f$ such that $f(1) = 1$. For $t \geq 0$ let $p_t$ denote the rank 1 projection onto the span of $e_1 + t e_2 \in \mathbb C^2$, then $f(p_0) = p_0$, $g(p_0) = 2 p_0$, and $\lim_{t \to 0} \| 2 p_t - 2 p_0 \| = 0$. However, for all $t > 0$, $p_0 \not\leq 2p_t$ since $\ker(2p_t) \not\subset \ker(p_0)$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, I should have tried something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Let $\textbf{1}$ be the identity, adjoin one if necesarry. You norm condition is equivalent to  $-\epsilon\textbf{1}< (b-g(a))$

$-\epsilon\textbf{1}< (b-g(a))\Rightarrow  g(a)-\epsilon\textbf{1}<b$ So choose an $\epsilon$ such that $f(a)< g(a)-\epsilon\textbf{1}$.

Comment: Makes sense until "choose an $\epsilon$ such that $f(a) < g(a) - \epsilon \mathbf{1}$". You can't do that because $f(t) = g(t) = 0$ outside the support of $g$... or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: I edited the image a bit to make my intention more obvious.

Comment: @Mike: Yes the new picture makes it clearer. I think that you need to add the assumption that $g(x)>f(x)+1$ on  $\sigma(a)$ (the spectrum of $a$). Then it should be fine because everything is happening there. The spectral theorem says that the unital $C^*$-algebra generated by $a$ is isomorphic to continuous functions on $\sigma(a)$. In this isomorphism $\textbf{1}$ is the characteristic function of $\sigma(a)$ NOT the function which is 1 on all of $\mathbb{R}$. So you can choose such an $\epsilon$ and then the rest of the proof should work.

Comment: True. But, alas, I don't want to make that assumption.

Comment: You have to make some additional assumptions for it to be true, for example in the picture you gave you can have $b=g(x)$ on support of $g$ and be very small $-\epsilon/2$ on some part of the complement of the support of $g$.

Comment: Ahh but I'm assuming $b$ is positive! You see? There's a little subscript $+$ lawyered in there :)

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps this is more subtle than I thought... I will have to give it more thought.